# Jquery + php, dont have a response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

good afternoon.

My problem is that when I send data with jquery.

I click on the button but do not receive a response. I think my problem was:

```
$.post("car.php",
            {
              action: "cargar_stock",
              cajas_dulce_de_leche: CajaDulceDeLeche,
              cajas_fruta: CajaFruta
            },
            function(data){
              alert("Data: "+data);
            }
        );
```

register.php:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cargar_carga() {

    var CajaDulceDeLeche = document.getElementById("cajaDl").value;
    var CajaFruta = document.getElementById("cajaFru").value;


    if ((CajaFruta != "") || (CajaDulceDeLeche != "")){
        $.post("car.php",
            {
              action: "cargar_stock",
              cajas_dulce_de_leche: CajaDulceDeLeche,
              cajas_fruta: CajaFruta
            },
            function(data){
              alert("Data: "+data);
            }
        );
    }   
    else{
        alert("Debe ingresar al menos algun valor");
    }
}
```

```
<label for="cajaDl">Dulce de Leche: </label>
<input type="text" id="cajaDl" />

<label for="cajaFru">Fruta: </label>
<input type="text" id="cajaFru" /><br/>
<input type="button" id="botonRegCaja" value="Registrar" onclick="cargar_carga()"/>
```

Here i recive the data from register.php

car.php:

```
<?php
include_once('helpers.php');
require_once("../some_libraries/config/db.php");

$port=3306;
$socket="";

$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, $port, $socket)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

if (isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] != "")) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    if ($action == "cargar_stock") {

        if (isset($_POST['cajas_dulce_de_leche']) && ($_POST['cajas_dulce_de_leche'] != "") &&
            isset($_POST['cajas_fruta']) && ($_POST['cajas_fruta'] != "")) {

            $boxs_to_stock_caramel = $_POST['cajas_dulce_de_leche'];
            $boxs_to_stock_fruit = $_POST['cajas_fruta'];

            $sql_stock = "SELECT `fruta`, `dulce` FROM `stock`";
            $result_query_stock = mysqli_query($con, $sql_stock);

            if ($result_query_stock) {

                $row_result = mysqli_fetch_array($result_query_stock);

                $row_dulce_stock = $row_result['dulce'];
                $row_fruta_stock = $row_result['fruta'];

                $total_boxes_caramel = $boxs_to_stock_caramel + $row_dulce_stock;
                $total_boxes_fruit = $boxs_to_stock_fruit + $row_fruta_stock;

                $sql_update_stock = '"UPDATE `stock` SET `fruta`='.$total_boxes_fruit.',
                                                            `dulce`='.$total_boxes_caramel.' WHERE id=1"';

                $result_sql_update_stock = mysqli_query($con, $sql_update_stock);

                if ($result_sql_update_stock) {
                    $result_gral = "Stock actualizado";
                }
                else{
                    $result_gral = "Problema con la consulta, stock no actualizado";
                }
            }
            else{
                $result_gral= "Problema al acceder a los datos del stock";
            }

        }else{echo "no llego bien el post";}
    }

}
echo $resul_gral;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.post("car.php",
            {
              action: "cargar_stock",
              cajas_dulce_de_leche: CajaDulceDeLeche,
              cajas_fruta: CajaFruta
            },
            function(data){
              alert("Data: "+data.alert);
            }, 'json'
        );
```

and in car.php try:

```
$varInfo['alert'] = 'Hello';
exit(json_encode($varInfo));
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! in the context of mi ¨index.php¨, when i include ¨register.php¨I lost the context in which I was running my program...
I have an index.php that this has a menu, I have different options in each of the options included different files .... Then my index.php includes register.php when car.php wanted to use this file in the same directory that you made ​​reference register.php. like I was right there, the problem is that my index.php is in a directory back!